# Change VAT Number in a invoice in a placed order

Tags: invoice, pdf, vat

I've a client who wants change the VAT Number in the invoice, but when i change it in the order at the billing section when i print the pdf for the invoice the VAT Number is the old.

How can i change this problem?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked that. If I go to the invoice, click on Billing Address > Edit, change the VAT number, save and print the invoice again, the VAT number is updated.

Comment: I tried this options but the PDF have the same VAT Number.

Comment: @Javier Which Magento version do you use? Do you use any extension for the PDFs?

Comment: Hello.
my version is 1.7.0.1 and is the default PDF Generator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed.

It was a problem with the cache, when you say if i change in  Billing Address i forget to see if the information after save had a cache cleaning, and yes, now it goes if i clean the cache after save the billing information.

Thanks you a lot.